# Excluding particular tests in Boost.Test

Tags: command-line-interface, boost-test

I need a behavior of non-existing option `test_launcher --exclude_test='Benchmark*'`? Is there a working mechanism in Boost.Test that can be used to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

In the test filtering documentation see the discussion on [Relative specification](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html#boost_test.runtime_config.test_unit_filtering.relative_specification) used with the command-line argument `--run_test`.

The *disabler* specification format is to preface the specification with an exclamation mark (`!`). So for your example the following will disable any enabled tests matching the pattern `Benchmark*`

```
test_launcher --run_test=!Benchmark*
```

Note that on linux you'll need to add quotes to prevent the asterisk and exclamation from getting interpreted

```
test_launcher --run_test='!Benchmark*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [labels](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/tests_grouping.html) instead, as it is an easy way to logically group your tests.

Boost.test provides then powerful unit test [filtering](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html) options from the command line, especially in your case the [disabler](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/test_unit_filtering.html#boost_test.runtime_config.test_unit_filtering.relative_specification) modifier.